# Why does this XML-Layout based Android Application crash?

Tags: xml, android, layout, crash

I am very new to Android Development. I am trying a sample application and it is generating a button dynamically using Java and it is working fine.

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    btn=new Button(this);
    btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    updateTime();
    setContentView(btn);
    }
```

This works fine in my emulator. However when i try do with an XML based layout, my app crashes in the emulator.

`Main.XML` contents

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button xmlns:android="com.testing"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:text=""
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        updateTime();

    }
```

Does anyone know why this simple application is crashing because of the XML layout?
Thanx a lot in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:text=""
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Anyway... it will help if you post your logcat output.

Comment: Yes! That seems to be the problem.... But i wonder why I cannot use my own namespace. Is this some sort of a constant namespace that cannot be changed? Or is it because this is linked with something that should be changed too in order for the application to work?

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
xmlns:android="com.testing"
```

should points to Android's XML Namespace... **NOT** your package name.

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

You can, however rename the word `android` to something else provided that the attribute value remains the same.